# File io in Java

Tags: java, file-io

For the following java program, I get this as the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: rawData.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:636)
    at Study_workshop.main(Study_workshop.java:15)
```

The program is a test program to learn how to write and read files. The rawData.txt file is in the bin and src files within the same directory as Study_workshop (so study_workshop.class and study_workshop.java). This is the program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintStream;




public class Study_workshop  {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {   
            //Declarations
            double unitPrice, quantity, total;

            //Calculations
            Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner(new File("rawData.txt"));
            PrintStream diskWriter = new PrintStream("cookeData.txt");
            unitPrice = diskScanner.nextDouble(); 
            quantity = diskScanner.nextInt();
            total = unitPrice * quantity;
            diskWriter.println(total); 
    }
}
```

Comment: move your file inside project folder(from bin to project parent folder). Default file path is in project folder as you given just file name.

Comment: Relative paths are resolved with respect to the directory from which the program is executed, not to any directory in which `.java` or `.class` files reside.

Comment: If your file is in /projectFolder/bin/ you should give this path to file constructor new File("/bin/rawData.txt"). By default constructor is looking in root directory of your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Study_workshop.class.getResource("rawData.txt") to get that file.

Some practice:

1. Use absolute path like /opt/data/xxx.txt if you can.
2. Use YourClass.class.getResource to get a file in the same directory of YourClass.class.
3. Use YourClass.class.getClassLoader.getResource to get a file in the `CLASSPATH` of YourClass.

**It is not a good practice to use relative paths because you never know WHERE and HOW your program is to be executed.**

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this error you can pass the fully qualified path to File constructor:-

```
Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner(new File("/home/sre/bin/rawData.txt"));
```

Answer (score 1):

when you execute your program the directory where you are pointing is the directory given by the user.dir property of the System class:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

So if your file is not in that directory you have to use absolute paths:

```
new File("yourPath/rawData.txt")
```